# Store values from dataset to a list

Tags: c#, sql-server, wpf, ado.net, dataset

I have created a Dataset from my database icluding two columns and I want to store all the rows of the second column(containing strings) to a list. How can I do that?

Comment: Take a look at Entity Framework. It makes working with databases much easier

Comment: Actually I heard alot of good things about Entity Framework but it seems complicated to me. I think for small project like the one I'm doing, ADO.NET is just sufficient.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `Select`?

```
 var myStrings = myDataSet.Tables[0].AsEnumerable()
                          .Select(x => x.StringColumn).ToList;
```

You could also use a loop:

```
var list = new List<string>();
foreach(DataRow row in myDataSet.Tables[0].Rows)
{
    list.Add((string)row["StringColumn"]);
}
```

Comment: Thanks Dave. Can I use a for loop to do this task?

Comment: What does ["StringColumn"] specify? I want to get all rows of the second column so what should I put here instead of ["StringColumn"]?

Comment: @MinhNguyen That's the name of the column you want to get values from.